# Why is there not always a collinearity problem when introducing interaction terms to a MLR or logistic model?

Tags: interaction, multicollinearity

Collinearity is described as occurring when an independent variable is a linear function of another variable(s).  Such that the variable in question can be consistently predicted given the other variable(s).  So given an interaction term (x1*x2) that is simply a function of x1 and x2, how is there not always a collinearity problem?

I think that the answer is somewhere along the lines that even though x1*x2 is a function of x1 and x2, there may not necessarily be a linear dependency among the variables. And this is the part that I am having trouble conceptualizing. Does anyone have any examples of this or an R code that I can run to understand this better?

Thanks,
WC

Comment: Why don't you work out a small example. Say, $(x_1,x_2)$ = $((-1,-1),(-1,1),(1,-1),(1,1))$.

Comment: x1 * x1 is not linearly dependent on x1.  (Although it's close).  So x1 * x2 certainly won't be. (It is non-linearly dependent).

Comment: @Jeremy When $x_1$ is a binary indicator variable (coded as $0$ and $1$), $x_1\times x_1 = x_1$ is *always* linearly dependent on $x_1$! You cannot say much in general about linear dependencies among the $x_i$ and $x_1\times x_2$ without making strong assumptions. As extremes, in the example I gave, $x_1\times x_2$ is linearly independent of the $x_i$, whereas if in every case either or both of the $x_i$ equal $0$, (regardless of what other values they might attain) then $x_1\times x_2$ is identically zero, making it linearly dependent on $x_1$ and $x_2$.

Comment: The interaction term is correlated with x1 and x2 but not perfectly. Thus, the estimation is numerically possible but the main effects can't be interpreted alone.

Comment: @whuber. In that case yes. OP didn't say anything about dichotomous variables though.